# Badge Drawable in BrowseFragment doesn't appear on Amazon TV

Tags: android-tv, leanback, amazon-fire-tv

I've got a `BrowseFragment` displaying some api-loaded content using the `Leanback Support Library`. I'm also showing a custom logo in the top right hand corner using the `setBadgeDrawable` method on the `BrowseFragment`. This logo is included in the apk in the res folder. It appears as expected on an Android TV emulator, however when I install the binary onto an Amazon Fire TV stick, the logo disappears. All other functionality of the application is identical on Amazon Fire TV.

The image is a PNG and here is how I'm setting it:

```
setBadgeDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));
```

Any reason why this would be happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Amazon Fire TV has a size limit on the image. Once I shrunk the image, worked just fine. Weird.